# Cannot construct constexpr array from braced-init-list

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, c++14, constexpr

I've implemented a `constexpr` array like this:

```
template <typename T>
class const_array {
  const T* p;
  unsigned n;
public:
  template <unsigned N>
  constexpr const_array(const T(&a)[N]): p(a), n(N) { }

  constexpr unsigned size() const { return n; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // works
  static_assert(const_array<double>{{1.,2.,3.}}.size() == 3);

  // doesn't compile
  constexpr const_array<double> a{{1.,2.,3.}};
  static_assert(a.size() == 3);
}
```

Why is it that the first `static_assert` compiles, but initializing `a` fails?I'm using gcc 6.2.0. I'm getting

```
: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
: error: 'const_array<double>{((const double*)(&<anonymous>)), 3u}' is not a constant expression
   constexpr const_array<double> a{{1.,2.,3.}};
                                        ^
test/const_array.cc:17:3: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
   static_assert(a.size() == 3);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You've defined `a` twice.  Also looks like an implicit conversion might be happening.  Do you get any improvement if you decorate the c'tor with explicit?

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel Making the constructor explicit doesn't help.

Comment: `a1` fails in clang with `pointer to subobject of temporary is not a constant expression`.

Comment: gcc head and clang head both agree that the first is valid but the second is not. msvc thinks both are valid.

Comment: this smells like a a compiler bug.

Comment: Lifetime of array in second case is limited and would produce dangling pointer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that the initializer of `a.p` is not a constant expression. It's failing §5.20/5.2:

> if the value is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null pointer value

In other words, only pointer values known to the linker are valid constants. (Also, in your example the pointer is dangling.)

The first `static_assert` doesn't trip this because `p` is discarded and the value of `n` is a constant expression. Constant expressions may have non-constant subexpressions.

This works:

```
static constexpr double arr[] = { 1.,2.,3. };
constexpr const_array<double> a{ arr };
static_assert( a.size() == 3 );
```

Credit to @Jarod42 for pointing out the issue in the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure that section applies. We don't have a prvalue pointer anywhere. Also, both gcc and clang allow `static_assert(const_array<double>{{1.,2.,3.}}.p[0] == 1.)` (assuming you make `p` public)

Comment: @Barry Since the value of `a` is a constant expression, bullet 3 applies: "if the value is an object of class or array type, each subobject satisfies these constraints for the value." `a.p` is a subobject of `a`, so bullet 2 applies to it. In your `static_assert`, the condition `<expr> == 1` is a constant expression, but `<expr>.p` is only its subexpression, which isn't allowed by itself as a constant expression.

Comment: But `a` is not a prvalue.

Comment: @Barry The paragraph describes which expressions are constant expressions. `a` is a declarator-id in this context, not any sort of expression. Given the `constexpr` specifier, its initializer full-expression is required to be a constant expression (§7.1.5/9). Churning through the rules for initializers (§8.6) is an exercise outside the scope of this question.

Comment: The bullet points in that paragraph are conditions on prvalues. We don't have a prvalue.

Comment: @Barry Unfortunately, I suspect that the phrase, "the full-expression of the initialization" may be an underspecified hole in the standard. The relevant standardese is §1.9/13-14, which specifies that the initialization of `a` is included in the full-expression, but neglects to assign a value category to it. (So it's not *not* a prvalue, either.) But the meaning is clear enough. Variables declared `constexpr` have values that meet §5.20/5, or otherwise both that paragraph and such usage of the `constexpr` specifier are rendered meaningless.

Comment: The static attribute is not the issue. It is the const requirment on the T pointer that causes a match failure, and that can't be done through the nested template arrangement in the question. Not in an easily readable way.

Comment: @Barry A prvalue is "an expression whose evaluation initializes an object...", so it seems reasonable to assume that "the full-expression of the initialization" is a prvalue. Besides, if it were a glvalue, then presumably it must refer to the entity being initialized, which would mean that you can't have automatic `constexpr` objects at all because they fail the "permitted result of a constant expression" rules.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that you cannot imbue the constant nature of the pointer to T in the inner template through the outer template's T parameter.

```
template <typename T> class const_array {
    const T * p;
    unsigned n;
public:
    template <unsigned N>
        constexpr const_array(const T(& a)[N]): p(a), n(N) { }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    constexpr const_array<double> ca{(const double []) { 1., 2. }};
    return 0;
}
```

I tried a few dozen permutations to get rid of the cast without success.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Barry, Yes it does. Both errors in the question were related to the fact that the pointer to T is not constant within the outer template so the compiler cannot find the inner template and there is no construct to guarantee the constant-ness of a pointer to T in the passing of T. It would be inappropriate (a bad hack) to do that within the outer template just to force the match.

Comment: @FauChristian "Both"? There's one error in the question.

Comment: Trivially comment out static_assert(a.size() == 3);