# Is there a way to use std::async with std::experimental::future?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, c++17

**Note: Below is illegal even in C++17!**

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <experimental/future>

using namespace std;

int step1(experimental::future<int>)
{
    return {};
}

int step2(experimental::future<int>)
{
    return {};
}

int step3(experimental::future<int>)
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    return async([](){ return {}; })
        .then(step1)
        .then(step2)
        .then(step3)
        .get();
}
```

C++1z provides two types of `future`:

1. `std::future`
2. [`std:experimental::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future)

However, `std::async` returns `std::future` only, so the code above is illegal. If `std::async` returns `std:experimental::future`, then it would be ok.

My question is:

**Is there a way to use `std::async` with `std::experimental::future` that makes the code above legal under C++1z?**

Comment: Actually [the concurrency TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/concurrency) is not included in C++17.

Comment: Wonder How does it compile, To me it is showing error at the include `<experimental/future>` I have used the `1z` flag though

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to use `std::async` with `std::experimental::future` that makes the code above legal under C++1z?

Nope. `std::async` returns a `std::future<T>` which, despite the name, is an entirely unrelated type to `std::experimental::future<T>`.

You would have to write your own version of `async` that gives you the new kind of `future`. A simplified version would be something like:

```
template <class F, class... Args,
    class R = std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<Args>...>>
std::experimental::future<R> new_async(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    std::experimental::promise<R> p;
    auto fut = p.get_future();

    std::thread thread([p=std::move(p), f=std::forward<F>(f),
        args=std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)] () mutable
    {
        try 
        {
            if constexpr(std::is_void_v<R>)
            {
                std::apply(std::move(f), std::move(args));
                p.set_value();
            }
            else 
            {
                p.set_value(std::apply(std::move(f), std::move(args)));
            }
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            p.set_exception(std::current_exception());
        }
    });

    thread.detach();
    return fut;
}
```

That doesn't support other launch policies like `async` does, but it's just a start.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! Really want Regular Void... At least `if constexpr` makes it easier, but still.

Comment: LOL. One thing leads to another and all that :)

Comment: @T.C. : Did you use `args=std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` over `args=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` for any particular reason? Doesn't that prevent `std::reference_wrapper<T>` -> `T&` transformation? Or is that a good thing?

Comment: @ildjarn It's what `std::async` does; I'm just following suit. (As a bonus, it makes `R` easier to write :P)

Comment: @T.C. Unrelated to this question, but what do you think of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41420301/2069064)? I don't think the answer posted is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It [seems like](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/future) `std::experimental::future` has the same constructors as `std::future`, so it should be possible to construct an `std::experimental::future` from an `std::future`. However, as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831639/is-there-a-way-to-use-stdasync-with-stdexperimentalfuture/42831980?noredirect=1#comment72774109_42831980) by [ildjarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636019/ildjarn) it actually isn't according to [the latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0159r0.html), so there seems to be no way to do this until the TS changes accordingly.

Comment: `std::experimental::future` constructs itself by a `std::experimental::future`, rather than `std::future`. See the below of the documentation you cited.

Comment: @xmllmx That would mean you can never construct an `std::experimental::future` because for that you would need to already have an `std::experimental::future`. The Note says *"For other constructors, see the documentation for std::future's constructor."* which means that `std::experimental::future` has all the constructors that `std::future` has and *additionally* one that takes an `std::experimental::future`. This should be checked against the current draft though.

Comment: The current draft [is not free](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=65242); the last free paper is [P0159](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0159r0.html) which clearly shows that there is _no_ constructor for or conversion from `std::future`. `std::experimental::future` is constructed from `promise`, `packaged_task`, `make_ready_future`, etc. in namespace `std::experimental::concurrency_v1`.

Comment: As to "*It seems like `std::experimental::future` has the same constructors as `std::future`*": no, its constructors are specified the same way (in terms of preconditions, exceptions thrown, noexcept, etc.) as `std::future`, but a copy/move constructor for `std::experimental::future` must _necessarily_ take a `std::experimental::future` in order to _be_ a copy/move constructor. ;-]

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have taken the shortcut in writing the documentation. But yes, there's no conversion.